# Apple TimeCapsule not working with ADSL

Tags: adsl, time-capsule

I have just got a Time Capsule for christmas.

I plugged the ADSL cable from the filter into the circle slot thats the "internet ethernet port".

However, it doesnt register, the little light doesnt go green and Airport Utility says "Ethernet Unplugged" on setup.

What I'm beginning to think is that I still need my router? Then my router has a cable going to the Time Capsule? Would be lame but is that how its suppose to wor

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question. Plug it to your router and it will work like magic. the cable from ADSL filter is a phone cable, not Ethernet.

Comment: So its not possible to have it be the router?

Comment: if that is your goal (use it as Internet router for all other computers) you will have to make sure your internet connection is provided as Ethernet cable. If the connection is via a phone cable, you will still need an ADSL modem between the line and your TimeCapsule

Comment: It can be the router, but it can't be the ADSL modem -- Time Capsules don't have ADSL hardware built in. If you had a separate router and ADSL modem before, then you can get rid of the router and only need the ADSL modem. If you had an all-in-one unit (which is much commoner) then you'll need to keep it.

Comment: Oh, and if you're in the UK, Time Capsule's don't do BT's weird PPPoA network encapsulation, so your ADSL modem will have to to PPPoA to PPPoE protocol conversion.

Comment: Ah okay, my current modem is my router. So I guess I can chain my modem to the time capsule and disable the router side of things on the modem to improve performance

Comment: @azz0r, true. Alternatively you can use your Capsule as a "client" device by just plugging it to one of the free ports on your existing router/modem. All your Macs will still be able to find/use it for backup etc.

Comment: I was hoping the time capsule acted as a modem, there are no hacks to get it to do that?

Comment: if you mean as ADSL or dial-up modem, then no. It cannot change analogue to  digital. The WAN interface is Ethernet which is not the same as a regular phone line :)

Answer (score 0):

The Time Capsule is a router/wireless access point with a backup disk, dual-band wireless, and a USB port for a printer or an external hard-drive.  It does not have modem capability.

It sounds as if you have a combined modem/ADSL-router from your service provider.  You can chain the modem/router and the TC, and you can use either or both for ethernet routing and WiFi access, but you will need the modem functions of your current modem/router to translate ADSL to ethernet.

*I plugged the ADSL cable from the filter into the circle slot thats the "internet ethernet port".*

If you mean a DSL telephone filter:

[image: DSL phone filter] those are meant to go between the phone line and each telephone or fax device in the house.  The DSL modem has to plugged into the raw phone line.  Don't use the filter there - it won't pass DSL.